# How facebook load pages?

Tags: ajax, facebook

I have read somewhere Facebook load pages by an hidden iframe by an Ajax call...Is this true??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook uses [something they call BigPipe](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/bigpipe-pipelining-web-pages-for-high-performance/389414033919), which splits the page up into a bunch of little "pagelets" that are individually loaded via AJAX.

In the image below, the areas highlighted in light-blue are individual pagelets.

[image]

Comment: To be clear - they are not loaded by ajax. all the pipes are loaded from one response.

Comment: Initially. After load, though, updates are being pulled in dynamically.

Comment: yes. but the main idea in BigPipe is that all the contents is loaded with one request. Also, to be precise - the data after the initial loading is being loaded with Comet.

Comment: not just js after loading full page new pages are loaded by iframe. ie. loading profile of a friend uses iframe.

Comment: I doubt they're using iframes.