# how to change url in browser url box?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I really wonder why facebook and google can change the url without reloading the page? they just change the block or content in their site.

I notice that when I am using facebook, when click on the "new feed" the url is "http://www.facebook.com/" and the page didn't reload, then i click on "messages" the url changed to "http://www.facebook.com/messages/" and the page still not reload just change the "content" block of the site.

So how do I change url without reloading the page?

**edit:** i got the answer.
there are 2 cases here:

- browser support html5 (Firefox 3.6 + etc.): using html5 history. (example: www.facebook.com => www.facebook.com/messages )
- browser dosn't support html5 (IE6, IE7, IE8 etc.): using hash tag (#) (example: www.facebook.com => www.facebook.com/#!/messages )

hope this help to who have doubt like me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked into the history API for Javascript?

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/history.html

EDIT: You could also use mod_rewrite with apache and then, but that would cause a refresh.

Or there is this JQuery Plugin

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Comment: is it HTML5? so what about IE?

Comment: @Alwayz Change: There is also https://github.com/balupton/History.js which has fallback for HTML4.

Comment: @pimvdb, thank for link, i'll try it, because i really need it, i build a website that full of ajax. i divide the web page into block, and load it block by block, so i need to find the way to change url. many thanks

Comment: I would suggest using modernizr to check for History API support, and then if it doesn't use the @pimvdb's suggestion as a fallback. You might also look into yepnope (http://yepnopejs.com/) for loading your fallback.

Answer (score 2):

The URL usually changes to http://facebook/#!messages, so the change of the "fragment" URL part doesn't make the browser reload the page. Instead, there is some JavaScript library that watches fragment changes and make appropriate requests in order to reload the page content.

The usage of `#!` is almost becoming a "standard" for doing these things, I've seen this used elsewhere (eg. on Twitter). I don't remember if they all use the same library or just the naming convention, but you should be able to dig about it on the fb/twitter developers pages.

Comment: i am not confuse about it, it is "http://www.facebook.com/messages/" not "http://facebook.com/#!messages" , I am using facebook right now. it is actually change the url not the hash.

Comment: That's strange.. I tried again, and it goes to "https://www.facebook.com/#!/messages/", with the hash-bang.. Also, it is surprising to me that the browser allow changing the URL without reloading the page (think about the security issue in allowing to do so..)

Comment: I got it @redshadow, because ur browser dosn't support html5. i tried with IE8 it change to www.facebook.com/#!/messages as what ur said. but not for firefox 4.0 (im currently using it)

Comment: You are right, I just tried with firefox 6, and it actually changes the URL as you say.. I'm investigating what it does actually do (and I'm gonna try creating a page that changes its URL to `https://paypal.com/login` :P)

Comment: I just found this https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/bigpipe-pipelining-web-pages-for-high-performance/389414033919 (linked from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120647/how-facebook-load-pages) that could be a good point to start digging :)

Comment: ahh !! great idea, change to paypal.com or facebook.com or ebay.com .. lol,, anyway, thank for the link to facebook engineering, it is very interesting ^_^

Comment: If you use Google-Chrome the url is just http://facebook.com/messages so I think they use the History API on browsers that support it. Internet Explorer uses http://facebook.com/#!/messages

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the Content-Location HTTP header for this purpose.  See [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for more info.

Comment: @drrchknlsn i have tried with Content-Location already, it doesn't work, i also look at facebook header after retrieve the content, it don't have content-location.

Answer (score 0):

I code on JSBin.com, mainly use CSS and HTML (Abandoned Javascript loooong time ago) and have a question. For example a page's URL is http://www.codingrules.com/
Well, using HTML, How can I change that URL to for example 
http://www.ilovecoding.com

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.