# loading items when user scroll down

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a database which has about 5000 books.  When user comes on the page, I don't want to load the books by using simple `select * from BOOkTABLE`, my approach is to go as the user needs it, so I want that as the user scrolls down I could fetch data from the Database. May be in chunks of 15-20 books, is that a good approach? Any alternative?

Secondly I have alphabets on top of div so if a user clicks on `"Z"` we could fetch the books starting with `Z` and show him in the DIV.

Comment: Do you mean AJAX paging such as found in the Facebook?

Comment: This can be achieved using window.onscroll and ajax

Comment: I agree but if there is some lib that he can use instead of writing the whole, as this is the normal thing now a days..

Comment: You may checkout the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120647/how-facebook-load-pages

Comment: @sємsєм Thank you.. Pipes.. really never heard of this lib/tech

Comment: Also you may checkout the following tutorial: http://youhack.me/2010/05/14/an-alternative-to-pagination-facebook-and-twitter-style/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by using `Ajax` on scroll down.Something like that:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {


    if ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'abc.php',
            async:false,
            data:"pagedata="+pageData ,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){

            }
        });



    }
```

});

In `abc.php` you can set the query according to your requirement and render the html(response) to be shown when scrolled down.

Comment: do you have a Fiddle or some reference? not sure what this would do? ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()

Comment: Nopes dear but let me clear it some type of a particular point.for e.g when you scroll down to a certain position a ajax request initiates and will hit abc.php

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, using ScrollTop() you can load iterations of data from your PHP after an interval of pixels has been scrolled.

You will need a PHP file, and JavaScript.

This is written freehand with no testing so I can't guarantee these will work, but try something along these lines:

JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// Set the number of pixels from the top you want the event to fire
// Select the number of books you would like to load each time
// i = number of loads you've called
var reloadAfter = 500;
var numberBooks = 20;
var i = 1;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() >= reloadAfter )
    {
       $.get("getbooks.php", {number:numberBooks , counter:i} )
             .done(function(data){
                   $('#books').append("Title:", data.title)
                              .append("Author:", data.author);
                   });


        reloadAfter = reloadAfter + reloadAfter; 
        i++;
    }
});
```

PHP

```
$numberBooks = $_GET['number'];
$i = $_GET['counter'];
$upper = ( $numberBooks * $i );
$lower = ( $upper - $numberBooks );

$get_books = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM BOOkTABLE WHERE id > $lower AND id < $upper');

echo json_encode($get_books);
```